# WooCommerce - Product Expiration based on custom meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom POST meta value entitled 'class_availability_dates', and am trying to use this meta value to expire a WooCommerce product if this value is less than today's date.

A few things to note: 'class_availability_dates' is formatted (Y-m-d) - the reason for the OR is because there are also products which technically also have a class_availability_dates, but it's just an empty string. (*this is for products that will NOT expire)

Here is my wp-cron, and callback function:

```
//function for class expiration wp-cron (*based on class_availability_dates)
function delete_expired_classes_daily() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('delete_expired_classes')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'delete_expired_classes');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'delete_expired_classes_daily');

//function for class expiration
function delete_expired_classes_callback() {    
    //get todays date
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'meta_key' => 'class_availability_dates',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'class_availability_dates',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'CHAR',
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'class_availability_dates',
                'value' => ' ',
                'type' => 'CHAR',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    );

    $classes = new WP_Query($args);
    if($classes->have_posts()) : 
        while($classes->have_posts()) :
            wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
        endwhile;
    endif;    
}
add_action('delete_expired_classes', 'delete_expired_classes_callback');
```

Where am I going wrong? I have a similar function, which works for the WP Admin side to sort the products based on the class_availability_dates - but I can't seem to figure out the expiration aspect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.